# Implementation of a simple stack with min method

Tags: c++, c++11, interview-questions, stack, queue

The problem statement:

> Implement a stack which has push and pop method and also min method whereas min method has \$O(1)\$ complexity.

From an interview standpoint, what mistakes would you point out in terms of algorithmic design and other things?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template<typename T>
class stack
{
  private:
    struct stackNode
    {
       stackNode(T val) : val(val), next(nullptr) {}
       stackNode() {next=nullptr;} 
       T val;
       stackNode *next;
    };

  public:
    stack() { first = min = nullptr; sz = 0;}
    ~stack()
    {
      while(first) {
        stackNode *tmp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = tmp;
      }
    }

    void print()
    {
      stackNode *tmp = first;
      std::cout << "Stack => "; 
      while(tmp) {
        std::cout << tmp->val << ", "; 
        tmp = tmp->next;
      }
      std::cout << std::endl; 
    }

    stackNode* push(T val, stackNode *head)
    {
      stackNode *tmp = new stackNode(val);
      tmp->next = head;
      return head;
    }

    void push(T val)
    {
      first = push(val, first);

      T tVal = val;
      if(min && (min->val < val)) {
        tVal = min->val;
      }
      min = push(tVal, min);
      sz++;
    } 

    size_t size()
    {
      return sz;
    }

    void pop()
    {
      if(first) {
        stackNode *tmp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = tmp;

        //pop min temporary
        tmp = min->next;
        delete min;
        min = tmp; 
        sz--;
      }
    }

    T minimum()
    {
      if(min) {
        return min->val;
      }
      return T();
    } 

  private:
    stackNode *first, *min;
    size_t sz;
};

using myStack = stack<int>;

int main()
{
  myStack s;

  s.push(10);
  s.push(100);
  s.push(33);
  s.push(55);
  s.push(17);
  s.push(9);
  s.push(201);

  s.print();
  std::cout << "Size of stack = " << s.size() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  s.pop(); s.pop();
  s.print();
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  s.pop(); s.pop();
  s.print();
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return head;` should be `return tmp;`, right?

Comment: @vnp thats correct, Im missing `head = tmp;` line before the `return head;`. I want to keep the return statement as it is for better readability as this method returns new `head`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

**Do not `#include <iostream>` in header files.** Most C++ implementations transparently inject static constructors into every translation unit that `<iostream>` is included in.  Instead, `#include <ostream>` and provide a stream parameter for library users.  In the event you only need to forward declare a `std::ostream` object, prefer `#include <iosfwd>`.

**`#include` only what you use.**  Every file should be able to compile on its own and should not rely on transitive includes.  Including `<string>` is unnecessary.

---

```
    struct stackNode {
      stackNode(T val) : val(val), next(nullptr) {}
```

**For input-only parameters, pass cheaply-copied types by value.  Pass everything else by reference to `const`.**  Any type can be represented by `T` as `T` is not constrained.  Since any type can be of any size, passing by value can be a very expensive operation.

**Avoid shadowing variable names.** When `-Wshadow` is checked, most pre-C++17 compilers will consider shadows names to be an error, even in the context of a class member initializer.

```
warning: declaration shadows a field of 'stack::stackNode' [-Wshadow]
       stackNode(T val) : val(val), next(nullptr) {}
                   ^
```

**When class data members are initialized with constants, prefer in-class initializers instead of member initialization.**  In-class initializers make it explicit that the same value is expected to be used in all constructors, avoids repetition, avoids maintenance problems, and leads to the shortest and most efficient code.

```
      stackNode(const T& value) : val(value) {}

      T val;
      stackNode* next{nullptr};
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

---

```
      stackNode() {next=nullptr;}
```

**Not all types have a reasonable default value.**  In the case where `T` is a primitive type (such as `int`), calling the default constructor of `stackNode` doesn't initialize `val` and any attempt to read `val` before writing is considered undefined behavior.

**Prefer in-class initialization and member initialization over assignments in the constructor body.** Some types cannot be assigned to.  Some types cannot be default-initialized.  When using assignment in the constructor body, members are first initialized and the assignment takes place.  For some types, this can be very expensive.

---

```
    ~stack() { /* ... */ }
```

**If you define or suppress *any* of the special member functions, define or suppress them *all*.**  This is known as the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

```
    // destructor
    ~stack() { /* ... */ }

    // copy/move construct
    stack(const stack&) { /* ... */ }
    stack(stack&&) { /* ... */ }

    // copy/move assign
    stack& operator=(const stack&) { /* ... */ }
    stack& operator=(stack&&) { /* ... */ }
```

---

```
    std::size_t size() { return sz; }
```

**Make member functions `const` by default.** Qualifying `const` expresses your intent that the objects observable state does not change inside the member function.  This enables you to catch changes to the observable state at compile-time and be able to use the member function with the object itself is `const`.  When you intend to have a member function change an object's observable state, then omit the `const` qualifier.

```
    std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
                       ^^^^^
```

---

```
    stackNode* push(T val, stackNode *head) { /* ... */ }
```

**Use class access modifiers to prevent users from calling member functions designed to be used internally only.**

**For pointers and references, prefer the C++ declarator layout.** C++ emphasizes types, not variables.  Anchor symbols to the type (`T*`) or leave them unanchored (`T *`).  Whichever you choose, be consistent. *Note:* This enforces the suggestion that you should only declare one variable per line.

```
  private:
    stackNode* push(const T& value, stackNode* head) { /* ... */ }

  public:
    void push(const T& value) { /* ... */ }
```

---

> From an interview standpoint, what mistakes would you point out in terms of algorithmic design

My main concern would be what questions you asked.  For a generic stack, maintaining a full list of minimums can be expensive.  If, through communicating, they were looking for a solution for an integral-based stack, a different approach could be used.

While you had a driver just to make sure everything compiled and ran, it would have been nice to see actual tests.

> and other things?

You had opportunities to reuse code.  Write an adaptor composed from two `std::stack`s or another standard container.  Instead of using raw pointers for resource handles (ownership), use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`). Manual memory management is tedious and error prone. Smart pointers are simple to use (`std::make_unique`/`std::make_shared`) and provide leak-freedom by default. *Note:* `std::make_unique` wasn't included in the C++11 library.  [You can find implementations on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902439/3762339)

Inline with the modern C++ approach, containers should have a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`.  `push`ing multiple values onto your `stack` would have been simplified.

---

**Recommended Resources:**

- [`const`-Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)
- [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)
- [C9 Lectures: Stephan T. Lavavej - C++11 Smart Pointers](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-3-of-n)
- [CppCon 2016: Herb Sutter's "Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE)

Comment: What do you mean by an "integral based stack"

Comment: A stack in which `T` is an integral type (i.e. `int`).

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer as its more detailed in c++ and really good in terms algo design.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends how much time you had to do this, overall it looks ok. In a couple of places you are initializing in the body of the constructor rather than using the initializer list, that is if nothing somewhat inconsistent but you should be using the initializer list in all of these cases. Also the way you use it, the `stackNode` constructor might as well take the `next` pointer, this way you don't forget to set it. I might try and get you to figure that out via questions about the constructor.

There is no way to get to value of the top of the stack, pop doesn't return it, neither is there a `top()` function that would return the top value.

I'd probably also would like to see an error condition rather than the default constructed value being returned for `minimum()` and `pop()`. It's worse for minimum because you are returning a valid value e.g. `int()` for an empty stack, i.e. calling `minimum()` on an empty `stack<int>` will return 0. That is just plain wrong therefore a bug.

I'd probably ask you why you consider `min` a temporary, this is from the comment in `pop()` just to clarify language.

`stackNode* push(T val, stackNode *head)` should be private

Algorithm wise it looks like a reasonable solution, depending on how the inteview goes i might ask you follow up questions, e.g. could you come up with a solution that doesn't need two separate stacks, these days I'd also ask you how to make this datastructure thread safe. I might ask what requirements there are to type `T` and what might happen if they aren't fulfilled. Maybe again depending how the interview goes, how to extend the stack to allow classes that don't fulfill the requirements to still used for the stack.

Comment: This took me 1:15 mins to implement right from understanding the problem to have a working code. Is it too long in your opinion?

Comment: Your follow up questions are really good btw. +1 for that

Comment: It's more a matter of did you implement this under time pressure or did you have all the time you needed (and your level of expertise), when we interview we have a problem for you to work at home at your own time, and then I like to watch people program in real time, the standards for both of these are different. In the first I'm looking for correctness and valid analysis of the problem given, in the second I'm looking if you can communicate your thoughts and reason about what you're doing. Other companies policies my differ.

Comment: Im implementing in home setting but under time pressure. but for sure, no way to mimic actual interview settings. Im 12 years exp in industry and have forgotten everything related to algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you had 15 minutes to implement the class, I think you did pretty good.

I have the following suggestions in addition to those offered by [the other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/174683/37893).

**Store both the value and the minimum value in `stackNode`**

```
struct stackNode
{
   // There is no need for a default constructor.
   // Passing everything that the struct needs to the
   // constructor helps simplify the implementation of push.
   stackNode(T val, T min, stackNode* next = nullptr) : val(val),
                                                        min(min),
                                                        next(next) {}

   T val;
   T min;
   stackNode *next;
};
```

That will make some of the functions simpler.

BTW, you have a memory leak since you are not deleting the stack of minimum values in the destructor.

**Replace `print` with `operator<<`**

Use of

```
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

is more idiomatic than using

```
s.print();
```

Here's how you could implement the `operator<<` function.

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, stack<T> const& s)
{
   cout << "Stack => "; 
   stackNode *tmp = first;
   while(tmp) {
      out << tmp->val << ", "; 
      tmp = tmp->next;
   }
}
```

This will work only if you declare the `operator<<` function a friend of the class.

**Move `private` parts of the class to the bottom**

The users of the class care only about the `public` section of a class. Hence, it makes sense to put them first in the class. The `private` section of a class are, to a large extent, implementation details. It is better to put them last in a class definition.

---

Here's an updated version of your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Forward declare the class template.
// It is necessary to declare the operator<< function.
template<typename T> class stack;

// Declare the operator<< function.
// This allows the friend declaration in the class and the
// implementation outside the class.
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, stack<T> const& s);

template<typename T>
class stack
{
   public:

      stack() { first = nullptr; sz = 0;}

      ~stack()
      {
         // Closed the memory leak.
         while(first) {
            stackNode *tmp = first->next;
            delete first;
            first = tmp;
         }
      }


      void push(T val)
      {
         // Simplified due to the new stackNode.
         first = push(val, first);
         sz++;
      } 

      size_t size()
      {
         return sz;
      }

      void pop()
      {
         // Simplified due to the new stackNode.
         if(first) {
            stackNode *tmp = first->next;
            delete first;
            first = tmp;
            sz--;
         }
      }

      T minimum()
      {
         if(first) {
            return first->min;
         }
         return T();
      } 

      // Make the operator<< function a friend of the class.
      friend std::ostream& operator<< <>(std::ostream& out, stack<T> const& s);

   private:

      struct stackNode
      {
         stackNode(T val, T min, stackNode* next = nullptr) : val(val),
                                                              min(min),
                                                              next(next) {}

         T val;
         T min;
         stackNode *next;
      };

      stackNode* push(T val, stackNode *head)
      {
         T min = val;
         if(first && (first->min < min)) {
            min = first->min;
         }
         return new stackNode(val, min, head);
      }

      stackNode *first;
      size_t sz;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, stack<T> const& s)
{
   out << "Stack => "; 
   typename stack<T>::stackNode* tmp = s.first;
   while(tmp) {
      out << tmp->val << ", "; 
      tmp = tmp->next;
   }
   return out;
}

using myStack = stack<int>;

int main()
{
  myStack s;

  s.push(10);
  s.push(100);
  s.push(33);
  s.push(55);
  s.push(17);
  s.push(9);
  s.push(201);

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Size of stack = " << s.size() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  s.pop();
  s.pop();
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  s.pop();
  s.pop();
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Minimum = " << s.minimum() << std::endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great `operator<<` suggestion, so is about min. I actually implemented this in1:15 mins which include reading problem to getting working code. Its bad considering 45 mins interview. What is your expectation of 12 years exp person to code this in (to get into top notch companies)?

Comment: @NulledPointer, I think solving this problem in 1 hour and 15 minutes is concerning for someone with 12 years of experience. That's my opinion, obviously. Others may have different expectations.